# How to get to the weapon machines in Southern Shelf - Bay marauder city?

Tags: borderlands-2

According to the map, there are two weapon shop machines right next to me:

[image]

But I cannot find either. I need to clear my inventory and sell some items. How to get to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're upstairs inside of a room where the boss [Midge-Mong](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Midge-Mong) spawns.  The entrance is on that diagonal section of thick wall on your map above the yellow arrow. If you haven't accepted or completed the mission [Symbiosis](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Symbiosis) I don't think you'll have access to this room.

[image: Entrance to room with vending machines in Southern Shelf - Bay]